# Enabling two-way communication between two classes

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, delegates, protocols

So I have a custom view `touchableView` inside a `ViewController`. 
`touchableView` informs `ViewController` of changes in its properties through a delegate protocol  (`ViewController` being the `delegate`).

**What is the best method to change properties of `touchableView` from `ViewController` (so the other way around)?**
Is there a way to create a two-way delegate relationship between two classes?

Comment: You have the touchableView object, so you can do what ever you want to do by using that object

Comment: You are right. I wasn't thinking straight and focused to much on communication via protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply:**

Assuming that you are already have `touchableView` instance in the `ViewController`, you should be able to set -or get-/call its properties and methods.

For instance, assume that you have the following method in `touchableView` class:

```
class func fromNib() -> TouchableView {
    return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: self), owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! TouchableView
}
```

You should simply be able to:

```
let touchableView = TouchableView.fromNib()
```

thus:

```
// for example
touchableView.myProperty = "Hello"
```

<sub>I assumed that `TouchableView` has a string property called `myProperty`...</sub>

---

**Remark:**

For some reason, I suggest to implement some of *property observers* in `TouchableView`:

> Property observers observe and respond to changes in a property’s
>   value. Property observers are called every time a property’s value is
>   set, even if the new value is the same as the property’s current
>   value.

They might be -somehow- useful to be implemented in your custom class. For clarity, let's consider -for instance- that if editing the value of `myProperty` should be effecting the background color of the view, it might be implemented as:

```
var myProperty: String = "Initial Value" {
    willSet {
        print("About to set value to:  \(newValue)")
    }
    didSet {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

---

**Further Reading:**

If you are looking for an advanced approach for *two way bindings* (Implementing MVVM), you might want to check [this article](http://artsy.github.io/blog/2015/09/24/mvvm-in-swift/).

I would also suggest to take a look at some frameworks that will be so helpful for such an approach, such as [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift), for a more simple framework, you might want to check [ReactiveKit/Bond](https://github.com/ReactiveKit/Bond).